Start/stop apps on windows lock screen
Our company wants to install a custom time-tracking app; is it possible to start the app when the user logs in/unlocks session, and kill it when they log out/lock session, using windows policy settings?

Of course it is. All that's needed is access to the Windows API that reports when a user gains or loses access to the screen, to catch lock / unlock, and the app simply gets started at login, and shut down (with the ability to report its shutdown time) on log out. However, that's a matter of programming and so more suited to a different area of these boards.
Edit: As per Greg Askew's comment: an app can be set to start running at login either via start script or as a scheduled task triggered at logon; and a scheduled task can also be triggered at lock and unlock to stop (or pause) and start (or unpause) the app. Logoff stops all apps associated with that user ID, so if the app records its stop time you should be good. You'd have to set a policy that would arm the scheduled tasks, and then it would be automatic on that station from then on.

I'm sorry, I forgot to specify: I meant to do it via Windows Policy, not by modifying the app.

You should re-word the answer to "use a scheduled task to start in the security event is for logon/unlock."
